# Missing constraints in Constraintlayout And hardcoded text

Tags: android-studio

Im Noob programmer with android studio, I added button (or anything) to my design will show below  error

> missing constraints in Constraintlayout And Hardcoded text

I searched this topic in stackoverflow, but can't luck.

Comment: did you add implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2' in app?

Comment: Where I added this?